# access information/state of another running app

Tags: ios, message

My question pertains to checking the state of the messages app, and whether a reply is currently being typed. I'm aware that on a non-jailbroken device, it is impossible to access the database of text messages, but I figured this might be a bit different?

Comment: Do you mean iMessage?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. Apps should not access other apps, that's what Apple calls app sandboxing:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html

> The purpose of a sandbox is to limit the damage that a compromised app can cause to the system. Sandboxes do not prevent attacks from happening to a particular app and it is still your responsibility to code defensively to prevent attacks.

Comment: there goes my million dollar invention! why doesn't apple understand not everyone wants to hack other people's phones.

Comment: I cannot answer that. Unfortunately, I am not in the iOS dev team ;)